# Laravel: How to prevent Mail to be send that is queued with Later?

Tags: laravel

I'm sending an email to a seller informing him that the buyer is coming soon.

```
Mail::to($order->buyer)
    ->locale($order->buyer->privacy->language)
    ->later($when->addHour(), new ReminderForBuyer($order));
```

However, I have a problem that there are cases, where the buyer can cancel his already paid order.

So how can I prevent sending this email out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the structure, not delaying the email with later. 
Just dispatch a new job `ReminderForBuyerJob::dispatch($order)->delay($when->addHour())`.

`ReminderForBuyerJob` will check if the order is canceled, if so dont send the `ReminderForBuyer`.

Comment: One little side question, I forgot to say that $when is set to pickup-time. That means this could be one week in the future. Can I even delay that long?